# Display recently purchased items in account dashboard for magento 1.7

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, dashboard

I am trying to modify my user account's dashboard. By default, magento has most recent orders section. I am trying to add another block below it which shows the 5 latest purchased items. I know this is possible, just haven't managed to solve it yet. Any help is greatly appreciated!!

I am using Magento Community Edition 1.7

Comment: Saw a similar question in another post, which could lead you in the correct direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8628797/get-product-information-of-the-latest-orders-in-magento

Answer (score 0):

Update the Dashboard controller `Mage_Adminhtml_DashboardController` to add the new action

i am giving you one reference answer of [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16620994/add-tab-in-admin-dashboard-magento-1-7-0-2) to manage our custom block in admin dashboard

it is for new product but you have to try with your self to make them happen latest item purchase.

i hope it will very helpful to you.